# yum stucks on update centos 5.6

Tags: centos

I have the following situation with my CentOs 5.6 64 bit:

```
[root@host ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
```

..and thats it. Nothing comes back, ctrl+c does not have any effect, it's getting stuck.

Any thoughts what to look after?

Comment: Adding `-d9` says?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to add new problems. Mark the correct answer to this question, then if you have a new problem ask a new question. I deleted your new question from this one, but you can recover it to copy and paste into a new question from the edit log.

Answer (score 3):

try `yum clean all` first and then `yum update`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are running a virtual machine or you are otherwise restricting yum's memory footprint.

If this is the case, you are simply running out of memory.  You can try:

```
ulimit -m unlimited 
ulimit -v unlimited
yum --noplugins update
```

If that does not work, please post the output from top after pressing M to sort by memory utilization.

Comment: I would probably also want to add some swap space anyway, by creating a swapfile (`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile.dat bs=1k count=512000; mkswap /swapfile.dat; swapon /swapfile.dat`), then adding it to /etc/fstab.